# Google App Engine's SDK compiles JSPs to class format 52.0, too high for server

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm facing a problem where Eclipse and the App Engine SDK are building JSPs with class format 52.0, which subsequently fails to deploy as the server only accepts java 1.7 classes.

I've seen a bunch of workarounds that tell me to use a 1.7 JVM to start Eclipse. However, this is not possible due to a corresponding client application already heavily using Java 8 features.

Is there a way to get Eclipse to either:

- Compile JSPs using 1.7 class formats?
- or, failing that, to use a 1.8 compiler, runtime, and `rt.jar` to suggest for, build, debug, and run a standalone Maven project?

Comment: What workarounds? Which version of Eclipse is this? In which JDK are you running the application? If the server only accepts 1.7 classes, isn't that something to settle against using 1.8 features?

Comment: @nitind Currently everything (Eclipse, client application) are running on Java 8 on Ubuntu. The workarounds I've seen all request that I use a 1.7 JDK to run Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse is probably not the one compiling the JSPs into their final form. What actually is? Why are you writing against Java 8 features when your server only supports 1.7?

Comment: @nitind I am not. All build settings are for 1.7. The 1.8 is a separate project. There is no JSP build level setting.